# Improve the implementation of worldquant 101 alpha factors using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, quantitative-finance, dolphindb

I was trying to implement 101 quant trading factors that were published by WorldQuant (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00991.pdf).

A typical factor is about processing stocks' price and volume information along with both time dimension and stock dimension.  Take the example of alpha factor #4: (-1 * Ts_Rank(rank(low), 9)).  This is a momentum alpha signal.  low is a panel of stocks' low price within a certain time period. rank is a cross-sectional process of ranking panel’s each row (a time snapshot). Ts_Rank is a time-series process of moving_rank panel’s each column (a stock) with a specified window.

Intuitively, the **Pandas dataframe** or **NumPy** matrix should fit the implementation of 101 alpha factors. Below is the best implementation using **NumPy** I got so far.  However, the performance was too low. On my Intel core i7 windows machine, it took around 45 seconds to run the alpha #4 factor with a 5000 (trade dates) by 200 (stocks) matrix as input.

I also came across  **DolphinDB**, a time series database with built-in analytics features (*https://www.dolphindb.com/downloads.html*).  For the same factor Alpha#4,  DolphinDB ran for mere 0.04 seconds, 1000 times faster than the **NumPy** version. However, DolphinDB is commercial software. Does anybody know better python implementations? Or any tips to improve my current python code to achieve performance comparable to DolphinDB?

**Numpy implementation** (*based on https://github.com/yli188/WorldQuant_alpha101_code*)

```
import numpy as np

def rankdata(a, method='average', *, axis=None):
    # this rankdata refer to scipy.stats.rankdata (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.1/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L9047-L9153)
    if method not in ('average', 'min', 'max', 'dense', 'ordinal'):
        raise ValueError('unknown method "{0}"'.format(method))

    if axis is not None:
        a = np.asarray(a)
        if a.size == 0:
            np.core.multiarray.normalize_axis_index(axis, a.ndim)
            dt = np.float64 if method == 'average' else np.int_
            return np.empty(a.shape, dtype=dt)
        return np.apply_along_axis(rankdata, axis, a, method)

    arr = np.ravel(np.asarray(a))
    algo = 'mergesort' if method == 'ordinal' else 'quicksort'
    sorter = np.argsort(arr, kind=algo)

    inv = np.empty(sorter.size, dtype=np.intp)
    inv[sorter] = np.arange(sorter.size, dtype=np.intp)

    if method == 'ordinal':
        return inv + 1

    arr = arr[sorter]
    obs = np.r_[True, arr[1:] != arr[:-1]]
    dense = obs.cumsum()[inv]

    if method == 'dense':
        return dense

    # cumulative counts of each unique value
    count = np.r_[np.nonzero(obs)[0], len(obs)]

    if method == 'max':
        return count[dense]

    if method == 'min':
        return count[dense - 1] + 1

    # average method
    return .5 * (count[dense] + count[dense - 1] + 1)

def rank(x):
    return rankdata(x,method='min',axis=1)/np.size(x, 1)

def rolling_rank(na):
    return rankdata(na.transpose(),method='min',axis=0)[-1].transpose()    

def ts_rank(x, window=10):
    a_rolled = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, window,axis = 0)
    return np.append(np.full([window-1,np.size(x, 1)],np.nan),rolling_rank(a_rolled),axis = 0)


def alpha004(data):
    return -1 * ts_rank(rank(data), 9)

import time

# The input is a 5000 by 200 matrix, where the row index represents trade date and the column index represents security ID. 
data=np.random.random((5000, 200))
start_time = time.time()
alpha004(data)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

--- 44.85099506378174 seconds ---
```

**DolphinDB implementation**

```
def WQAlpha4(low){
    return -mrank(rowRank(low, percent=true), true, 9)
}

// The input is a 5000 by 200 matrix, where the row index represents trade date and the column index represents security ID.
low = rand(1000.0,5000:200);
timer WQAlpha4(low);

Time elapsed: 44.036 ms (0.044s)
```

Comment: Something like DolphinDB is a specialised product and can focus on pulling out all of the stops, probably using a low-level programming language. It will be impractical to beat unless you also drop down to a better language.

Answer (score 4):

This part of the code:

```py
return np.apply_along_axis(rankdata, axis, a, method)
```

...is going to be quite slow. Function application like this means more of the computation runs in Python, and relatively little of it runs in C.

There's a much faster solution available here, if you're okay with a slight change in how your rank function is defined. Specifically, the below code is equivalent to changing from `method='min'` to `method='ordinal'`. On a test dataset of random numbers, it agrees with your method 95% of the time, and only disagrees by 1 where it is different.

By using argsort along the axis, numpy can do the entire calculation without dropping into Python.

```py
def rank(x):
    return (data.argsort(axis=1).argsort(axis=1) + 1) / np.size(x, 1)


def ts_rank(x, window=10):
    a_rolled = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, window, axis = 0)
    rolling_rank_fast = (a_rolled.argsort(axis=2).argsort(axis=2) + 1)[:, :, -1]
    # Fill initial window - 1 rows with nan
    initial_window = np.full([window-1,np.size(x, 1)],np.nan)
    return np.append(initial_window,rolling_rank_fast,axis = 0)


def alpha004(data):
    return -1 * ts_rank(rank(data), 9)
```

Benchmarking this, I find it runs roughly 100x faster.

Comment: This is a great solution! On my laptop, it takes only 0.37201786 seconds. It's a rocket-style speedup!